# Find $P[X<2Y]$ where $0<y<x<1$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

$X$ and $Y$ are random variables with joint density function given below

$f{_X}{_Y}(x,y)$ = $8xy$, where $0 < y < x < 1$

I know I am supposed to draw a region and then find new limits of integration

Could any one find the limits of integration for this one?

This one seems rather tricky since y is dependent on x.

Comment: Where is your drawing of the domain of integration? Sorry but providing one would be more effective than invoking some rather mysterious "gaps in [your] knowledge"...

Comment: @Did please see my response to ImNotTheSaxMan's answer and see if you can clarify my misunderstanding. Thank you.

Comment: Hmmm... I must have missed your drawing, where is it?

Comment: @Did hahah dude I used Wolfram alpha for the drawing and so pretty sure it was correct. I even used the right limits, just integrated the other way around i.e $dxdy$ which is why my answer was in terms of x i.e  2x^2−.5∗x^2. And I though this was incorrect since x can take values up to 1, and that may make my answer > 1. So tell me...what was it that I was doing wrong?

Comment: Still no drawing posted... Where is this going? You seem to insist on providing no personal input to the question. ("Dude".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the entire region looks like a triangle contained within the unit square, and the integral over the whole region looks like the following:
$$
\int_0^1\int_0^x 8xy\,dy\,dx = 1
$$
We wish to calculate $P[X<2Y]$, which is the portion of the triangle above the line $y=x/2$. If I am not mistaken, this gives us the following integral:
$$
\int_0^1\int_{x/2}^x 8xy\,dy\,dx
$$

Comment: Thank you for your response. These are the limits I came up with but I integrated the other way around, which gave me the answer in terms of x i.e. $2x^2−.5∗x^2$ . would you say this correct? Since x can take values upto 1, won't this give a probability great than 1 (at times)?

Answer (score 1):

For the general problem of this kind you set up a double integral as follows. $$\int_0^1\int_0^x xy.dy.dx$$

Imagine a vertical strip of infinitesimal thickness $dx$ at some distance $x$ along the $x$-axis: you first integrate from $y=0$ to $y=r$, because the limit is the line $y=x$. The variable $x$ behaves as a constant in this integration, as you are integrating along a vertical strip along which $x$ is contant - at the value $x$. Because of this, the integral can be recast as $$\int_0^1x\int_0^x y.dy.dx .$$ Doing the *inner* integral first, you get $$\int_0^1x.{x^2\over2}.dx .$$ Now the integrand is a finction of $x$ alone, so you have $$\int_0^1{x^3\over2}.dx$$$$=$$$$\left[{x^4\over8}\right]_0^1 = {1\over8} .$$

I've just realised that your function had a factor of 8 in to begin with ... so the result here is 1.

This is a very *pleasant* double integral, in which you can use that trick of 'integrating-out' one of the variables first to get a function purely of the other, and then integrating with respect to *that* one. They aren't *anywhere near* so pleasant generally - mainly by reason of the region of integration not being a simple shape such as a triangle. Complexities of the function *itself* tend to be less of a problem ... as long as you do the inner integration over a region - in this case a vertical strip - over which the other variable is constant.

Actually, you could simplify this even more by noting that the integral is symmetrical in $x$ & $y$, whence you could have just put the limits [0,1] into both the inner *and* the outer integral, and halved it at the end. Tricks like that - *and much* more cunning ones - are often *extremely* efficacious in the solution of complicated double (or  triple ... or higher-order, even) integrals.